# Decoding assignment python

Tags: python

Our assignment is to take a key txt file that has a cipher's key, apply it to an encrypted text file to produce a decrypted file.

I can not seem to get the decryption to work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    keycode = {}

def key(filename):
    with open("key.txt", "r") as infile:   
        for line in infile:
            parts = line.split()
            plain = parts[0]
            code = parts[1]
            keycode[plain] = code

        return keycode

key("key.txt")


decrypted_text = []
with open ("encrypted.txt" , "r")as infile:
        for c in infile:
            if c in keycode:
                c = keycode[1]
            decrypted_text.append(c)

with open("decrypted.txt" , "w") as outfile:
      for line in decrypted_text:
          outfile.write(line)


print "Decrypted.txt has been written."
```

Comment: When you say you can't get it working, what do you mean? Are you getting an exception? Bad output? If so, please give details (for instance the expected and observed outputs, or the traceback from an exception).

Comment: Sorry, the encoded text is my name coded.  ipmmz The output of the decrypted should be holly.  It will only return ipmmz, no matter what parameters I try to get it to look at.  I have also tried dict.get() and can not get it to work.  There are no errors, just the incorrect output.

Comment: What is the contents of `"key.txt"`? How exactly is the encryption supposed to work?

Comment: The Key is a dictionary that state A:B, C:D, etc.

Comment: @Bickknight--this is what the key text file looks like:                  A    B
B    C
C    D
D    E
E    F
F    G
G    H
H    I
I    J
J    K
K    L
L    M
M    N
N    O
O    P
P    Q
Q    R
R    S
S    T
T    U
U    V
V    W
W    X
X    Y
Y    Z
Z    A

Comment: Well....that didn't quite work.  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is `for c in infile:`. You're not iterating over a `string`, but a `file`. To get the content of the `file`, you need to call the `File.read()` method.

Second problem is `keycode[1]`, which gets the first element of the `keycode` dictionary, whatever its content. `keycode[c]` is the correct way.

```
with open ("encrypted.txt" , "r") as infile:
    for c in infile.read():
        if c in keycode:
            c = keycode[c]
        decrypted_text.append(c)
```

This is what the keyfile should look like:

```
i h
p o
m l
z y
```

`i` is substituted for `h`, `p` -> `o`  and so on. Keep in mind that the dictionary index is case-sensitive, so `H` is different than `h`. And again, you're iterating over a file, in this case you need the `File.readlines()` method in your `key()` method.

Comment: @Holly, I just added some more details what you got wrong.

Comment: OK!  SO it is SORT OF WORKING!!!!  This is the output I get JQNNA.  So I am using the wrong "match"?  But how?

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!!!  It works!!!  I just had to change my function to call the opposite one.  I truly appreciate your help!!  This will raise my grade by a letter!  :)  :)